# Олимпиадная задача

Tags: java, олимпиада

Прошу помочь решить задачу. Задача оч сложная.  https://pastebin.com/RPKf1nsJ

Сам пробовал, мало что получилось.
Крепкий орешек.

решить нужно на java :(

описание:

Условие задачи

Ограничение времени, с  1
Ограничение памяти, МБ  64
Общее число попыток отправки    15

По пятницам мы часто играем в популярную ролевую игру "Релиз до выходных" с коллегами. Правила этой игры довольно сложны и предполагают хорошую стратегию и планирование. Чтобы иметь представление о последствиях тех или иных ходов, часто хочется понимать, насколько вероятен тот или иной исход ситуации, с учетом разных вариантов выпадения игральных костей.

Необходимо написать программу, которая сможет, приняв на вход последовательность операндов и операций, вывести все возможные варианты результата и их вероятности.

Выражение на входе может содержать скобки, и следующие операторы в порядке уменьшения их приоритета:

- – умножение

- и - – сложение и вычитание

> - левый операнд больше, чем правый. Результат равен 1, если истинно, и 0 - если ложно

В качестве операндов могут выступать:

n - целые положительные числа, либо 0 (0≤n≤100 000)
dn - результат броска игральной кости, где n целое положительное число, количество граней (1≤n≤100). Результатом будет равномерное распределение вероятностей между всеми гранями (от 1 до n). Каждый такой операнд в выражении – это результат отдельного броска (например, d4+d4 – это сумма результатов двух разных бросков четырехгранной кости).

Входные данные (поступают в стандартный поток ввода)
Одна строка без пробелов, содержащая выражение для вычисления. Выражение гарантировано вычисляемое и не содержит синтаксических ошибок. Максимальная длина строки 110 символов.

Выходные данные (ожидаются в стандартном потоке вывода)
Одна или несколько строк, в каждой из которых есть два числа, разделенных пробелом:

1. целое – один из вариантов результата
2. вещественное - процент вероятности такого варианта с математическим округлением до 2 знаков и разделителем .
   Строки на выходе должны быть отсортированы от меньшего результата к большему.

Примечание к округлению - в связи с округлением вероятностей - суммарная вероятность всех исходов может быть не равна 100%, это нормально, компенсировать это в решении не нужно.

Пример 1
Ввод:

2+2
Вывод:

4 100.00

Пример 2
Ввод:

d4+2
Вывод:

3 25.00
4 25.00
5 25.00
6 25.00

Пример 3
Ввод:

d4+(d6>2)
Вывод:

1 8.33
2 25.00
3 25.00
4 25.00
5 16.67

Примечания по оформлению решения
Возможно использование только стандартных библиотек языков, установки и использование дополнительных библиотек невозможны.

При отправке решений на Java необходимо назвать исполняемый класс Main. В решении не нужно указывать пакет.

Примеры работы со стандартными потоками ввода и вывода
Для JS можно использовать readline и console.log:

const readline = require('readline').createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
readline.on('line', (line) => {
// Введенная строка в переменной line, тут можно написать решение и вывести его с помощью console.log
...
console.log(String(result));
readline.close();
}).on('close', () => process.exit(0));

в Python можно использовать встроенные функции input() и print():

line = input()
...
print(result)

в Java можно использовать java.util.Scanner и System.out.println:

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();
...
System.out.println(result);

Перед отправкой решения рекомендуем запустить тесты из раздела Тестирование, они помогут поймать синтаксические ошибки и ошибки выполнения.

Comment: по ссылке пусто, советую скопировать условие сюда.

Comment: Приведите текст задачи и ваши попытки её решить. Никаких ссылок никуда не надо.

Comment: опять задача со вступительных в школу яндекса? Вам помощь навредит, если вы не можете её решить самостоятельно, то вы в школу не поступите даже с нашей помощью

Comment: покажите ваши попытки решить и какие у вас проблемы возникли и я может смогу подсказать, куда вам двигаться.

Comment: там было 2 задачи. одну я решил сам. эту вообще не понял. начал писать парсер математического выражения, чтобы сначала раскрыть скобки, сделать умножения. но потом понял, что это вроде как вообще не нужно и запутался. не понимаю, как решать эту задачу

Comment: я не программист, наверное проблема в этом...

Comment: когда вы к кому то конкретному обращаетесь, указывайте его ник вот так @Denzl

Comment: вам сложно потому что вы видимо проигнорировали [рекомендуемые материалы для подготовки](https://school.hh.ru/reference) ну и справедливости ради, задача эта действительно непростая.

Answer (score 2):

Я эту задачу решил и вот что мне помогло:

- Сначала я разбил строку на токены, чтобы знать, где операция, а где операнд или набор значений
- Потом я, используя алгоритм сортировочной станции, построил абстрактное синтаксическое дерево
- По дереву уже гораздо проще найти все возможные значения выражения
- Используя хештаблицу можно найти сколько раз конкретное значение получалось в результате
- Зная распроеделение значений можно найти процентное соотношение.

Вот и все шаги по сути.